# How to get SpringBoot to find my file in the src/main/resources directory

Tags: java, spring-boot, filereader

I have the following class (below). The file corresponding to vocabLookupFile is found when in the root directory of my SpringBoot project. However, I really want it in the src/main/resources directory of the project. With the below setup, it is not found there. By the way, the LookupMapper component is autowired in a @Service class, and other than not finding the file in src/main/resources, it works fine.

I am hoping someone can tell me how to modify the below so it can be found there. Thanks for any ideas.

```
@Component
public class LookupMapper {

    public HashMap<String, LookUp> entry = new HashMap<>();

    @Autowired
    public LookupMapper(@Value("${vocab.lookup.mapper}") String vocabLookupFile) throws IOException {

        try (CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(vocabLookupFile))) {
            String[] values = null;
            while ((values = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
                LookUp lookUp = new LookUp(values[1], Boolean.parseBoolean(values[2]));
                this.entry.put(values[0].toUpperCase(), lookUp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The important thing to realise is that resources are not files on the file system, they are files in a JAR. As such, you cannot use `FileReader`, which can only read from the file system. You need to use `Class.getResourceAsStream` or another method for loading resources (Spring has several).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I see. So I am reading now using: ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader(); classLoader.getResourceAsStream(vocabLookupFile) . Unfortunately that just introduces a new problem which is that I have to find a different way to parse the csv since CSVReader requires FileReader. In fact most reading options require FileReader. So I don't know how to address the FileReader requirement.

Comment: Are you sure `CSVReader` requires a `FileReader`, and not just a `Reader`? If the latter, you can wrap the `InputStream` in an `InputStreamReader`.

Comment: do you mean like this?: new FileReader(new InputStreamReader(classLoader.getResourceAsStream(vocabLookupFile))); If so, this does not compile (cannot resolve constructor FileReader(java.io.InputStreamReader)

Comment: No, `new InputStreamReader(classLoader.getResourceAsStream(vocabLookupFile))` (or a variant that explicitly specifies the character set)

Comment: ugh, right (my bad). Good now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as per Mark Rotteveel, suggestion, with my file in the resource directory, in general, I need a solution that could retrieve the file from the context of the jar (and those things in the jar are considered "resources"). I used Classloader to get the resource as a stream. So the below works for me. Thanks to Mark.

```
@Component
public class LookupMapper {

    public HashMap<String, LookUp> entry = new HashMap<>();

    @Autowired
    public LookupMapper(@Value("${vocab.lookup.mapper}") String vocabLookupFile) throws IOException {
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();

        try (CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(classLoader.getResourceAsStream(vocabLookupFile)))) {
            String[] values = null;
            while ((values = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
                LookUp lookUp = new LookUp(values[1], Boolean.parseBoolean(values[2]));
                this.entry.put(values[0].toUpperCase(), lookUp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```